# Rust type annotation on left side of let pattern matching

Tags: rust, move, let, borrow

The compiler will complain that z is moved and can not be referenced anymore:
[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20x%20%3D%20100%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20z%20%3D%20%26mut%20x%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20z1%20%3D%20z%20%3B%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20*z1%20%3D%20200%20%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20z)%20%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20%3C%3D%3D%20compile%20error%0A%7D)

```
let mut x = 100 ;
let z = &mut x ;
let z1 = z ;   
*z1 = 200 ; 
println!("{}", z) ;  // <== compile error
```

> error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `z`

While the following code works well:
[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20x%20%3D%20100%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20z%20%3D%20%26mut%20x%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20z1%3A%20%26mut%20i32%20%3D%20z%20%3B%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20*z1%20%3D%20200%20%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20z)%20%3B%20%0A%7D)

```
let mut x = 100 ;
let z = &mut x ;
let z1: &mut i32 = z ;  // type annotation added to left side
*z1 = 200 ;
println!("{}", z) ;
```

The only different is that the latter has type annotation added to left side of let clause.
I wonder what is the different between them.